# Unterschied zwischen riskieren und wagen

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich würde gern wissen, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen „riskieren“ und „wagen“ gibt?

- Sind sie Synonyme?
- Wenn nicht, wann verwendet man welches?

Beide haben auf Englisch die Bedeutung: "to risk/dare".

Comment: Der Duden hilft manchmal und vermeidet *"off-topic"* Fragen - siehe [riskieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/riskieren) oder [wagen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wagen)

Comment: Ein Unterschied: *riskieren* kann man sowohl eine Aktion (den Sprung) als auch den Einsatz (die Gesundheit); *wagen* kann man nur die Tat, nicht den Preis.

Answer (score 9):

"Riskieren" und "wagen" haben eine sehr ähnliche Bedeutung, die implizite Wertung ist allerdings unterschiedlich. Wenn der Sprecher das Risiko als vertretbar empfindet, wird eher das stärker positiv besetzte "wagen" verwendet, sonst das stärker negativ besetzte "riskieren".

> Er wagt den Sprung über den Graben.

impliziert eher Mut, Verwegenheit, (kontrollierte) Risikobereitschaft.

> Er riskiert den Sprung über den Graben.

impliziert eher Risiko, Gefahr, bis hin zu Verantwortungslosigkeit.

Comment: Es gibt auch noch das schöne Wort *Wagnis*, das ebenfalls weit weniger negativ behaftet ist als das Wort *Risiko*.

Comment: zwei einzelne Beispiele die völlig gleich klingen reichen nicht aus um getrennte semantische Räume zu belegen. Zudem wäre "*Wie können Sie es wagen!?!*" eventuel ein Gegenbeispiel--oder etwa nicht und die Floskel ist deshalb relativ höflich?

Comment: @vectory Semantische Räume? So hoch wollte ich es gar nicht hängen, mir ging es um die unterschiedlichen Konnotationen und Wertungen. Was "Wie können Sie es wagen?" betrifft, hier würde ich - ebenfalls ohne linguistische Fachmethodik - zwei unterschiedliche Einschätzungen des Risikos sehen. Person A tut etwas, das mit Risiko behaftet ist, findet das Risiko aber vertretbar ("wagen"). Person B findet das Risiko nicht mehr vertretbar ("riskieren") und reagiert mit "Wie können Sie das unter 'wagen' einstufen, das ist doch eindeutig 'riskieren'".

Comment: "*Wie können Sie es wagen?! Sie riskieren eine ganz schön dicke Lippe!*" appeares like a graded escalation indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt viele Überschneidungen. Ein Beispiel, wo man die beiden Verben nicht als Synonym verwenden kann, ist wenn man sagen möchte, dass jemand Gefahr läuft, dass ihm selbstverschuldet etwas passiert:
"Wenn du zu spät kommst, riskierst du, dir Ärger einzuhandeln." Das würde keiner durch "wagst du" ersetzen.

Answer (score 3):

Wie meine beiden Vorredner bereits ausgeführt haben, sind beide Wort in ihrer Bedeutung ähnlich, aber nicht identisch.
*Etwas riskieren* vereint dabei die Bedeutungen von *etwas wagen* und *etwas auf's Spiel setzen*.
*Etwas wagen* bezieht sich immer nur auf die eigene Handlung (auch wenn diese als Substantiv dargestellt wird und auf den ersten flüchtigen Blick wie ein Objekt erscheint wie in: *Ich wage einen Blick*)
*Etwas riskieren* kann auch die Bedeutung von *etwas auf's Spiel setzen* haben, d.h., man riskiert den Verlust von etwas, das man hat, entweder als (Wett-)Einsatz mit der Chance auf Gewinn (*Ich riskiere am Pokertisch 1000 Euro*) oder bei einer nicht bewusst wahrgenommenen oder für unrealistisch eingeschätzten Gefahr (*Wenn Du da rauf kletterst, riskierst Du Dein Leben*).
Drittens kann - wie bereits von Peter P dargelegt - *etwas riskieren* sich auch auf eine sich aus dem eigenen Handeln (oder Nicht-Handeln) ergebende Konsequenz beziehen.

Auch Henning Kockerbecks Hinweis auf die unterschiedliche positive oder negative Wertung stimme ich zu, wenngleich es sich hierbei eher um Nuancen handelt.

Comment: Ja, hab's korrigiert, danke für den Hinweis. Das kommt davon, wenn man die Antwort dreimal ergänzt und umformuliert